# How to set "interval id" to state in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to create an app that allow to create a list of timers. Each timer may be paused and resumed.

```
const [time, setTime] = useState({ hours: 0, minutes: 0, seconds: 1 });

useEffect(() => {
    const tick = () => {
        const duration = moment.duration(
            moment.duration((moment().format('X') - data.unix) * 1000, 'milliseconds') + 1000,
            'milliseconds'
        );
        setTime({ hours: duration.hours(), minutes: duration.minutes(), seconds: duration.seconds() });
    };

    const timer = setInterval(tick, 1000);

    return () => {
        clearInterval(timer);
    };
}, [data.unix]);
```

That's all I have for now and I'm trying to make a pause option that I think could be implemented by clearing interval to stop the timer. But timer is in useEffect scope and can't be accessed to delete outside useEffect. If i put timer in setState it causes error. Any advices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in order to keep reference to the interval outside of `useEffect` you should use `useRef`

this will allow clearing the interval on an event handler like: onClick for example.

```
const IntervalComponent = (props) => {

    const intervalRef = useRef();
    
    
    useEffect(() => {
              intervalRef.current = getInterval();
            return () => clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
          }, []);
        
        const getInterval = () => {
            const startTime = new Date().getTime();
            const progressInterval = setInterval(() => {
              // do on each interval
            }, 10);
            return progressInterval;
          };

    
    const onClickHandler = (e) => clearInterval(intervalRef.current);

    return <button onClick={onClickHandler}>Clear interval</button> ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I made this kind of working example (with RN, but the logic stays). I mocked the functionality of **moment library**: https://snack.expo.io/@zvona/setinterval-example

Like explained in the already upvoted answer, you need to use `useRef` when working with `useEffect` and intervals.

Core functionality:

```
const App = () => {
  let timer = useRef();
  const [time, setTime] = useState({ hours: 0, minutes: 0, seconds: 1 });
  const [toggleLabel, setToggleLabel] = useState('Pause');
  const tick = useCallback(() => {
    // mock:
    const duration = {
      hours: () => '0'.padStart(2, '0'),
      minutes: () => '0'.padStart(2, '0'),
      seconds: () => (''+ Math.floor(Math.random() * 60)).padStart(2, '0'),
    };

    setTime({
      hours: duration.hours(),
      minutes: duration.minutes(),
      seconds: duration.seconds(),
    });
  }, []);

  const startTicking = () => setInterval(tick, 1e3);
  const stopTicking = () => clearInterval(timer.current);

  const toggleTimer = () => {
    const shouldPause = (toggleLabel === 'Pause');
    timer.current = shouldPause ? stopTicking() : startTicking();
    setToggleLabel(shouldPause ? 'Resume' : 'Pause');
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    timer.current = startTicking();

    return () => {
      stopTicking();
    };
  }, [tick]);

  const { hours, minutes, seconds} = time;
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>{`${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`}</Text>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.toggleButton} onPress={toggleTimer}><Text>{toggleLabel}</Text></TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};
```